# curl waits in cygwin before sending the actual request

Tags: java, curl

I am running curl from cygwin like this

`$ curl -v -i -X POST 'http://www.abc.com:10123/myapp/abc' -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --data-binary "@input.json"`

It starts connecting and hangs at this line STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x8001f150; line 1074 (connection #0) for 149986ms and then is able to connect and send the request (traces shown below). Now the question is why it waits for that long? How can I skip this wait time?

Thanks.

```
 STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x8001f150; line 1027 (connection #-5000)
 About to connect() to www.abc.com port 10123 (#0)
   Trying ::1...
 Adding handle: conn: 0x80059548
 Adding handle: send: 0
 Adding handle: recv: 0
 Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
 0x8001f150 is at send pipe head!
 - Conn 0 (0x80059548) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
 STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x8001f150; line 1074 (connection #0)
 After 149986ms connect time, move on!
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
 Connected to www.abc.com (127.0.0.1) port 10
```

Comment: try [curl force IPv4 – disable IPv6 in curl](http://www.businesscorner.co.uk/disable-ipv6-in-curl-and-php/). Better now?

Comment: The method in that link didn't work for me on Cygwin, but the --ipv4 curl option did